# Jenkins pipelines credential variable not getting passed

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Can't seem to figure this one out, the variables seems to be null when I run the following step (in my pipeline):

```
        steps {
            withCredentials([certificate(credentialsId: 'pfxCert', keystoreVariable: 'pfxPath', passwordVariable: 'pfxPassword')]) {
                powershell '''
                $keyContainerName = "somekey123"
                $cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
                $cert.Import($pfxPath, $pfxPassword, [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::Exportable)
                $exportPrivateKeyInformation = $true
                $certXml = $cert.PrivateKey.ToXmlString($exportPrivateKeyInformation)
                $csp = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.CspParameters
                $csp.KeyContainerName = $keyContainerName
                $csp.Flags = [System.Security.Cryptography.CspProviderFlags]::UseMachineKeyStore -bor [System.Security.Cryptography.CspProviderFlags]::NoPrompt # -bor is biwise or
                $csp.KeyNumber = [System.Security.Cryptography.KeyNumber]::Signature
                $rsa = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider $csp
                $rsa.FromXmlString($certXml)
                $rsa.Clear()
                '''
            }
```

Here's the error output:

```
powershell.exe : Exception calling "Import" with "3" argument(s): "Array may not be empty or null.
```

I have another step with secret text credentials working, but it uses bat instead of powershell. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please try to minimize your example, did you try to echo the credentials without calling powershell?

Comment: Hi and thanks! Yes I tried to echo the both variables and it shows as empty / null. I also tested the same step, but with batch command and the variables has the values, so it seems like powershell isn't able to get the values properly.

Comment: [JENKINS-52799](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-52799)